# Android 3rd Party Library - Asking for my application's API Key

Tags: android, api, key, api-key

Anyone have any idea what this is or where I can get it? I thought it would just be some function on the activity or something but all I can find is an API key for google maps when I try to search for help with this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which 3rd party library is it?  You need to get the API key from them, probably through some sort of registration process.

Comment: I believe it is called Papaya Mobile.

Comment: From their website it doesn't seem like the SDK is publicly available yet? You would need to get the API key from them.

Comment: It's not the game SDK if you click on "Offer" at the top of the website, it's that SDK that is asking for it.

Comment: I think we figured it out, apparently we didn't add our application to their listing after we made an account but thanks for the help!